# If x is an object of a class D that has a default constructor returns a new class D object (so different from x!) JAVA

Tags: java

THIS IS THE TEXT OF OLD EXAM OF MY UNIVERSITY, THAT I DON'T UNDERSTAND.

If x is an object of a class D that has a default constructor returns a new class D object (so different from x!).
Otherwise print "Class D does not have a default builder!".

THIS IS THE INTERFACE:

```
public interface Refli {
    Object echoType (Object x);
}
```

THIS IS THE MAIN:

```
public class TestRefli {

    static class OneClass {
        public OneClass (int n) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Refli R = new MyRefli();

        String S = "UnaStringa";
        OneClass U = new OneClass(7);

        Object result1 = R.echoType(S);

        if (result1 != null) {
            System.out.println(S == result1);
            System.out.println(S.getClass() == result1.getClass());
        }

        Object result2 = R.echoType(U);

        if (result2 != null) {
            System.out.println(U == result2);
            System.out.println(U.getClass() == result2.getClass());
        }

        /*
        Print:
        false
        true
        The Class oneClass haven't a costructor
         */
    }
}
```

THIS IS THE CLASS THAT SHOULD BE IMPLEMENTS:

```
public class MyRefli implements Refli {

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. can you please be more clear?

Comment: also: in your description it says that there is a Default constructor, yet you've added one which takes a parameter ..

Comment: I think they want you to use reflection to inspect the class of the object that is passed in to see what kind of constructors it has. Start with `x.getClass()` and then look at the Javadoc for `java.lang.Class` to see how you can list the available constructors. Also see `Class#newInstance()` and what kind of exceptions it can throw.

Comment: @Stultuske :the OneClass constructs are given by the professor, it is not the default constructor of MyRefli .... genuinely not even I understand this trace

Comment: @Thilo I did not understand what you mean